# How do I find Meridia's Beacon in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I started the quest "The Break of Dawn", but when I set the quest as active it won't give me a quest marker. It also did this with the "The Legend of Red Eagle" but after a few hours, it randomly added a marker.

Will it do this with Meridia's Beacon as well, or do I have to restart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Beacon will spawn in a random chest after you reach level 12,hence it has no set location.

You can use [Clairvoyance](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Clairvoyance) to find the beacon. Alternately, you can go the [Statue to Meridia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Statue_to_Meridia) and speak to Meridia to begin the quest. (This will set a way point to the Beacon.)

More detailed guide [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Break_of_Dawn).

Comment: So if there was no quest marker for it and I set it as active clervoince would still show the way?

Comment: Btw I'm level 81

Comment: Yes,but i recommend going to the statue since clairvoyance can easily just confuse you  and lead you to the closest quest instead the selected one.

Comment: It dosent matter now I started a new file and I have 10 deadric artifacts btw thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Arremer's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/64154/15184) answer which is accepted. But if you still have problems then follow along:

`I started the quest "The Break of Dawn", but when I set the quest as active it won't give me a quest marker.`

There are two ways to start the `Break of Dawn` quest. The required level for this quest is 12.

1) Either you find Meridia's beacon while questing. It does spawn randomly.

2) The other option is to visit Meridia's statue, in which case she asks you to find the beacon in some camp. IF this is the case then the quest marker activates as long as your quest journal has that quest active. In this case `Clairvoyance` should help as long as this quest is active in your journal and no other quests are active.

If you used console commands `advlevel`or `setlevel` to get to the level 12 requirement for this quest, it will not start at all. To correct this, use `player.setlevel 11` to get to level 11 and then level up normally or use `incPCS` to level up some of other skills to level up to 12. [Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Break_of_Dawn)

Apart from this I have not encountered any bugs related to this quest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the existing answers actually address what is likely happening here.

Generally speaking, for any of the randomly spawned quests (especially radiant quests), they can spawn anywhere that allows for it.  For both Skyrim and Solstheim, the quest markers work fairly well, however, sometimes they will not span the two correctly.  For example, a quest that spawns in Solstheim whose destination is Skyrim may not show a quest marker until you return to Skyrim.

This situation is exacerbated by installing Mods that add new lands which have destinations that support radiant quest destinations, for example Falskaar or Beyond Skyrim: Bruma.  In the case where the destination is not on your current "map", the quest marker will not appear.  Once you travel to that "map", the quest marker will appear, and you can complete the quest.